# Why does console.log() keep on going in this loop?

Tags: javascript

I defined a variable 'i' to be equal to 2, and then say: if 'i' is between 0 and 2, let the function 'animate' run. However, if I open up the console in JSFiddle (option-command-I), the console.log() continues decreasing by 1 below 0! Am I using the conditional in the if statement improperly?

```
var interval = window.setInterval(animate, 500);
var i = 2;
if (0 < i < 2) {
    function animate() {
        alert('run');
        i--;
        console.log(i);
    }
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/lpsternotes/RuLHn/

Comment: `0<i<2` doesn't work as intended. Also, your animate function being called doesn't have the condition-check.

Comment: Why are you putting a function definition inside an `if`? What are you expecting that to do?

Comment: Try not to invent any "syntax". Stick to the book.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to clear interval once you satisfy the condition and move the if condition (note that `0 < i < 2` needs to be split into 2 conditions joined with && but here you can just do) with modification inside the function.

```
var interval = window.setInterval(animate, 500);
var i = 2;
function animate() {
    if (i > 0) {
        console.log('run');
        i--;
        console.log(i);
    }
    else{
        window.clearInterval(interval);
   }
}
```

Comment: This explains the `if` part better than my answer, because by the time I'd written out the logic of `0 < i < 2`, you'd already written it better than I would have done, and I didn't want to plagiarise. :)

Comment: @IMSoP No, you did great!!  I really did not want to explain that.. But you did really well, i just shortened it up, hoping OP will discover himself why... I was focusing on his issue especially when it almost cranked my browser.. :D lol!!! According to me your answer is the best and you have my +1.

Comment: Another silly question: why does console.log() only log one number, not each number from 5 to 1 as the loop runs? http://jsfiddle.net/lpsternotes/RuLHn/2/

Comment: @LNA Thats because of my stupidity... check my answer update and this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/wzuH7/

Comment: @PSL Oh cool, thanks! Is the else { window.clearInterval(interval); } clearly needed, though? http://jsfiddle.net/lpsternotes/wzuH7/1/

Comment: @LNA Yes because still your interval is executing the callback eventhough you are not using it. So it is consuming a thread when JS at a browser level is single threaded. You need to clearInterval if it is no longer needed.

Comment: Ah, okay. Note to self: always pair window.setInterval with window.clearInterval.

Answer (score 4):

There are two problems here.

Firstly, there is this: `0<i<2`. This will always evaluate to `true`.

Why? What you hoped it meant was "i is between 0 and 2" (which could be written as `0<i && i<2`). But to a JS compiler, it is just two instances of the `<` operator. First, `0<i` is evaluated, resulting in either `true` or `false`; then, that result is compared against `<2` - so we have either `true<2` or `false<2`. In order to answer that question, JS must "cast" the `true` or `false` to an integer. It treats `false` as `0`, and `true` as `1`; since these are both `<2`, the final result is always `true`.

Secondly, there is the position of your `if` statement, which is checked only once:

```
if (0 < i < 2) {
    function animate() {
```

If you read through the code, you will see that there is no way of getting back to the line above this `if` statement, since the only repeating part of the code is the interval repeatedly running the `animate` function. To run each time the function runs, the `if` needs to be inside the `function`, not the other way around.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you put if statement inside your animate function?

```
var i = 2;
function animate () {
    if (i> 0 && i<2) {
        alert('run');   
        i--;
        console.log(i);
    } 
}
```

Edit: 
 1) you might want to use i>0 && i<2 rather than 0

2) Not sure if you do need to clear the interval after the condition is met. Would be better if you could elaborate a bit more about your requirements.